# How to control user access to Bitbucket through Git?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am migrating a project from SVN to Bitbucket.

Now I need to give access permissions to a list of users that I have as a list of username and password in a text file.

How can I do that in Bitbucket without manually adding each user?

Comment: I don't know Bitbucket well but I'd guess it's like GitHub: everyone creates their own user account, and then yes you have to add the users to groups for each access permission. There's probably a bulk UI for creating groups. But unless there's a trivial mapping from the file you have to the user accounts each user has created I don't think you can just re-use them. (And you shouldn't have their passwords, should you?) Is this the public Bitbucket.org, or a private enterprise version?

Comment: Just an fyi. Git doesn't restrict access, servers do that.

Comment: Sorry I dont have the passwords... Just the usernames of those whom the access should be granted

Comment: Is this for Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org) or Bitbucket Server?

Comment: Bitbucket cloud

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to use Groups.

If your bitbucket is connected to `LDAP` (standalone or via JIRA) you can grant or prevent access using those groups.

[image]

---

If you don't have LDAP groups you can use git hook which will read the list of users form file and will verify if the user is allowed to perform the desired task. for example in your `pre-receive` hook.